# How to get a sub-shape of an array in Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Not sure the title is correct, but I have an array with shape (84,84,3) and I need to get subset of this array with shape (84,84), excluding that third dimension.

How can I accomplish this with Python?

Comment: What do you mean 'excluding that third dimension'? You need to specify exactly which subset you want. If you are using `numpy` for example, this would be very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
your_array[:,:,0]
```

This is called slicing. This particular example gets the first 'layer' of the array. This assumes your subshape is a single layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using numpy arrays, using *slices* would be a standard way of doing it:

```
import numpy as np

n = 3  # or any other positive integer
a = np.empty((84, 84, n))

i = 0  # i in [0, n]
b = a[:, :, i]

print(b.shape)
```

I recommend you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/5472354).